# Return GIF from a method in Python

Tags: python, gif

I have a list of images which I'm converting into a gif like so:
`imageio.mimsave('name.gif',images)`
I want to do something like this:

```
define return_gif(images):
    # convert images to gif
    return gif
```

I checked various methods using ImageMagick, imageio, opencv but haven't found a function that creates the gif without saving it to disk. Help!

Comment: What is the point of making an in-memory GIF. You cannot do anything with it until you save it to disk without messing with the headers. Otherwise, you might as well just save the image pixels in BGR array format.

Comment: It's a fair question. You don't necessary want to save an image right away or at all; you might want to do further processing on it. I've definitely written programs where I created images in memory that never get saved to disk.

Comment: Yes, but with the headers and formatting specific to the format? Why put that all together and add the headers if you are going to process it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From imageio’s docs: https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html

You can pass a file object with a read() / write() method.

So if you want the encoded string for the gif, just make a class with a write method that adds to a string like this:

```py
class GifReader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gif = b""
    def write(text):
        self.gif += text
```